# Transferring selected row to another table

Tags: javascript

I fetched the data from the database and display it in a table with check boxes. What I want to do is the selected row should move into the second table and I don't want the checkbox column in the Second table Here's the code:

```
 <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Business Identifier</th>
        <th>Site Name</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Postcode</th>
    </tr>
    @if (Model.UserAccountSummary != null && Model.UserAccountSummary.Any())
    {
        foreach (var item in Model.UserAccountSummary)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>

                   <input name="Id" type="checkbox" value="@item.business_customer_identifier" class="chkclass"></td>

                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.business_customer_identifier)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.customer_name)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.postal_town)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.postcode)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    }

</table>
```

Here is the JS code:

```
$().ready(function () {
        $(".table").on("click", ".chkclass", function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                var trItem = $(this).closest("tr").clone();
                trItem.add("<tr>").append("</tr>");

                $("#targetTable").append(trItem);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Move or copy ? .. right now you are copying it to second table with clone method..

Comment: I am trying to copy records, currently it is copying the checkbox selection as well. How to omit Checkbox

Comment: Just put : trItem.find("input").remove(); ater clone method..

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $().ready(function () {
        $(".table").on("click", ".chkclass", function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                var trItem = $(this).closest("tr").clone();
             trItem.find("input").remove();
                trItem.add("<tr>").append("</tr>");

                $("#targetTable").append(trItem);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but currently i don't want to remove any records from Source table, i just wanted to copy records with no checkbox selection on the second table

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $(".table").on("click", ".chkclass", function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).closest("tr").appendTo("#targetTable");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the JS code for copying records from one table to another without checbox selection in the destination table:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $().ready(function () {
            $(".table").on("click", ".chkclass", function () {
                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    var trItem = $(this).closest("tr").clone();
                    trItem.find("input").remove();
                    trItem.add("<tr>").append("</tr>");

                    $("#targetTable").append(trItem);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```